# This tag needs [folding] into [code-folding]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

The [folding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folding) and [code-folding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-folding) tags are identical:

> Code folding is a feature of some text editors that allows one to
>   ‘fold’ (collapse/hide) and ‘unfold’ (expand/reveal) large blocks of
>   code.

Versus

> Code folding is a feature of some text editors and IDEs that allow
>   some text to be temporarily hidden or "collapsed" in order to hide
>   detail.

I think code-folding would be preferable as the surviving tag, as "folding" might get be confused with the functional programming concept [fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fold).